# How to return sequence value in sqlldr from unix shell

Tags: text-processing, oracle-linux, sql

I have a test.txt file with column (`Serialnumber,value`).

test.txt:

```
"SEQ_IN_AMT.NEXTVAL",123123
"SEQ_IN_AMT.NEXTVAL",123114
```

here `SEQ_IN_AMT` is a sequence name create on Oracle. Now, when I load this file through `sqlldr` in unix to Oracle `db.i` want the value of this sequence so that I will use this sequence value in below procedure:

```
P_UPDATE_VALUE (SEQ_IN_AMT.NEXTVAL,value)
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the format of the file `test.txt`, use `awk`:

```
awk -F'[",]' '{printf "P_UPDATE_VALUE (%s,%s)\n",$2,$4}' test.txt
```

Prints:

```
P_UPDATE_VALUE (SEQ_IN_AMT.NEXTVAL,123123)
P_UPDATE_VALUE (SEQ_IN_AMT.NEXTVAL,123114)
```

- `-F` defines the delmiters `awk` should use `"` and `,` in this case.
- `printf` formats the output as desired
- `$2` and `$4` are the both fields, based on the delimiters